# {N} and Angular http.post with https url

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

This is my first question on here so bear with me.

I have an app, in {N} and Angular, with a post request to login to my server. With a http.post using a http url works but when i change to a http.post using a https url, it no longer logs me in.

The strange bit is, it works in a browser but not in my app. As for the server cert, it's a proper bought one so its not running into a cert warning.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is the code in the function called by the login button:

```
this.userService.login(this.user)
  .subscribe(
    () => this.router.navigate(["/all"]),
    (error) => { 
      alert("Unfortunately we could not find your account.");
      console.dump(error) 
    }
  );
```

And this is the code of the http call:

```
 login(user: User) { 
     let headers = new Headers(); 
     headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
     headers.append("Accept", "application/json"); 
     let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true }); 
     let data = "j_username=" + user.username + "&" + "j_password=" + user.password; 
     return this.http.post(Config.apiUrlS + "static/auth/j_spring_security_check", data, options); 
}
```

---EDIT---

So it turns out that the android emulator and device ive tested the app on dont like the RapidSSL SHA256 CA cert we have on the server. Is this the reason why it doesnt work?

Comment: Post usable code where you think problem might occur.

Comment: Also, console output helps

Comment: @mast3rd3mon please edit your question to include them

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Also, welcome to SO, please take some time to read the how to ask a good question guide. It will help you get answers to your questions. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @toskv i've edited my question

Comment: @mast3rd3mon either select all your code and press the `{ }` button in the editor, indent every line with 4 spaces or (if it's just 1 sentence) between backtics (` `)

Comment: Keep in mind that if you test iunder iOS it is expected as by design iOS app are not allowing HTTPS requests.. in order to enable HTTPS requests in iOS look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/32331282/4936697

Comment: It's currently being developed for android